# Repetición de caracteres dentro de un ciclo while

Tags: c++, winapi

El programa consiste en que un usuario puede iniciar sesión a partir de un nombre y contraseña guardados en un archivo de texto. Por ejemplo, tengo 3 datos de usuario dentro del archivo que están acomodados del siguiente modo:

- Mariana 123456
- Eva05 505
- Ricardo 145

(Obviamente sin los puntos xd)

Si yo ingreso cualquiera de los 3 nombres en el programa, el dicho reconoce que coinciden con los guardados en el archivo de texto. Sin embargo, con las contraseñas solo funciona con los datos de la primera fila, al continuar el ciclo se presenta este problema:

[image: Esto sucede sucede en el primer recorrido del while]

[image: Esto sucede en el segundo (lo cual no ocurre cuando los datos coinciden con los de la primera linea del texto]

[image: Y ya por ultimo, en la tercera y ultima vuelta del while]

¿Que tengo que hacer para que no se repitan los datos a partir de cada recorrido?

```
case IDOK: { //Inicar Sesion

        GetWindowText(hEDIT1, usuario.nombre, 256);
        GetWindowText(hEDIT2, usuario.contrasena, 256);

        string name, contraseña;
        char nom[256];
        char contra[256];
        char contra2[256];
        ZeroMemory(contra2,256);
        contra2[0] = ' ';
        /*int n = name.length();
        int c = contraseña.length();*/

        ifstream archivo;
        archivo.open("usuario.txt", ios::in);
        if (archivo.fail()) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Error al buscar usuarios", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
            exit(1);
        }
        bool muchosmensajes = true;
        while (archivo.good()&& muchosmensajes) {
            archivo >> name;
            if (!archivo.eof()) {
                getline(archivo, contraseña);
                /*MessageBox(NULL, "Usuario", ":D", MB_OK);*/
                strcpy(nom, name.c_str());
                strcpy(contra, contraseña.c_str());
                strcat(contra2, usuario.contrasena);
                /*MessageBox(NULL, "Usuario", ":D", MB_OK);*/
                int n, c;
                n = !strcmp(usuario.nombre, nom);
                c = !strcmp(contra2,contra);
            /*  c = !strcmp(usuario.contrasena, contra);*/
                if (n&&c) {
                //if ((!strcmp(usuario.nombre, nom)) && (!strcmp(usuario.contrasena, contra))) {
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Usuario Registrado", ":D", MB_OK);
                    muchosmensajes = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (muchosmensajes) {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Usuario No Existe", ">:(", MB_OK);
        }
        archivo.close();
        EndDialog(ventana, NULL);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es todo un clásico.

Los mecanismos de lectura no son homogéneos, o al menos no todo lo homogéneos que podrías esperar, aunque tiene su razón de ser.

Para leer una serie de enteros, tu podrías poner el siguiente código:

```
int var1, var2, var3;
std::cin >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;
```

Y esto funcionaría ante entradas tan dispares como

- Números separados por uno o varios espacios

  ```
  1 2 3
  ```
- Números separados por una o varias líneas

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  ```
- Números separados por uno o varios tabuladores

  ```
  1 2   3
  ```
- Cualquier combinación lineal de las anteriores

Esto sucede porque el operador de extracción entiende que los separadores se están empleando justamente para separar los diferentes valores, entonces decide ignorarlos.

Sin embargo hay otras funciones que no hacen esto. Como por ejemplo:

- Lectura de caracteres

  ```
  char c;
  std::cin >> c;
  ```
- Lectura de líneas

  ```
  std::string linea;
  std::getline(std::cin, linea);
  ```

En estos casos los separadores no se descartan porque la función no puede determinar si esos separadores forman realmente parte del dato a leer o no.

La solución para estos casos es descartar el separador a mano:

```
if (!archivo.eof()) {
    archivo.ignore(); // Descartamos un caracter - el separador
    getline(archivo, contraseña);
```

Claro que si asumes que la contraseña no va a tener espacios, entonces puedes usar el operador de extracción y te olvidas de eliminar caracteres a mano

```
if (!archivo.eof()) {
    archivo >> contraseña;
```

Por cierto, procura no utilizar caracteres no ASCII para nombres de variables, al menos en C++. Es algo que puede darte problemas al compilar el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario, aprecio que se haya dado el tiempo de contestar. Pero hice los cambios que sugirio y sigo presentando los mismos problemas :(

Comment: @Jade https://wandbox.org/permlink/ubvyltHGZrpXOskJ. Si haces limpia de código y pasas a usar `std::string` en vez de `char[]` tal vez encuentres otros fallos menores en el código

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo voy a checar

Comment: ¡MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS! Ya lo cheque y funciona perfectamente ;w;